# oracle regular expression to check string contains both alphabet and number and does not contain special characters

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

How to create an Oracle regular expression to check whether the given string contains both number and alphabet and does not contain special character.
For example,

> if the string is like 'kjds327' it must **return true**
>
> if the string is 'dkfsdsf' or '132564' or 'asjv@3#34342fd' it must
> **return false**

Comment: I edited your post to remove all references to pl/sql. That is not another name for Oracle SQL - and your question has nothing to do with pl/sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` as follows:

```
select * from your_table
 where regexp_like(your_column,'([a-zA-Z][0-9]+)|([0-9][a-zA-Z]+)')
   and not regexp_like(your_column,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db2e1f7e53c2df62b0d7a83795ce0c83)

You can use `CASE` statement with this `regexp` in `SELECT` clause if you want true and false as a result.

Comment: For your first regex pattern, you may just simplify to `REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z]', 'i')`, using a simpler pattern in case insensitive mode.

Comment: Yeap. That can also be done @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

You could make three calls to `REGEXP_LIKE` for each required assertion:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[A-Za-z]') AND       -- contains alphabet
    REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[0-9]')    AND       -- contains number
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[^A-Za-z0-9]');  -- no special character
```

Note that here I am assuming that a "special" character is any non alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single regular expression for this task.

A moment's reflection will reveal that a string that must contain at least one letter and at least one digit, and contains ONLY letters and digits, **must** contain either a letter followed immediately by a digit, or a digit followed immediately by a letter. I won't spend much time on this, since it's a matter of basic logic (not of Oracle SQL programming).

With this insight, the solution becomes clear. You need something like this (using POSIX bracket expressions). Don't forget the anchors `^` and `$` to make sure that the entire string is matched, not just a part of it.

```
with
  sample_inputs(string) as (
    select 'kjds327'        from dual union all
    select 'dkfsdsf'        from dual union all
    select '132564'         from dual union all
    select 'asjv@3#34342fd' from dual union all
    select null             from dual union all
    select '8B'             from dual
  )
select string,
       case when regexp_like(string, 
  '^[[:alnum:]]*(([[:alpha:]][[:digit:]])|([[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]))[[:alnum:]]*$')
         then 'true' else 'false' end as test_result
from   sample_inputs
;

STRING         TEST_RESULT
-------------- -----------
kjds327        true 
dkfsdsf        false
132564         false
asjv@3#34342fd false
               false
8B             true
```